# Casella exercise 4.58: $P(X/Y \leq t)$ with $X$ and $Y$ uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ independent uniform (0,1) random variables:

Find $P(X/Y \leq t)$ and $P(XY \leq t)$

I started with: $P(X/Y \leq t)$ by using Jacobian:

So, $Z= X/Y$,  $W = Y$ , my Jacobian gave me: $w$

$F_{Z,W}(z,w) = w$ .

From now on I started to have some problems to define the interval of $F_{Z}(z)$.

Z as I can see goes from zero to infinity right?

The answer in Casella is: $F_{Z} = 1/2 (t)$ , for $t>1$ and $1/2 - (1-t)$, for $t \leq 1$

Any help guys?

Comment: Have you tried drawing the sample space and sketching the region where $X/Y\leq t$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your way certainly works, but a direct calculation is also possible. First note that the range of $X/Y$ is $\mathbb{R}^*$ (the set of all positive reals). The subtleties of this problem is probably to notice the probability depends on the value of $t$. If $t \leq 0$, then clearly it is $0$. If $t \in (0, 1)$, then $yt \in (0, 1)$ for all $y \in (0, 1)$, hence 
$$P(X/Y \leq t) = \int_0^1 P(X/y \leq t) f_Y(y) dy = \int_0^1 P(X \leq yt) dy = \int_0^1 yt dy = \frac{1}{2}t.$$
Similar argument shows that for any $t > 1$, 
\begin{align}
P(X / Y \leq t) & = \int_0^1 P(X/y \leq t) f_Y(y)dy = \int_0^1 P(X \leq yt) dy \\
& = \int_0^{t^{-1}} yt dy + \int_{t^{-1}}^1 dy = \frac{1}{2}t^{-1} + (1 - t^{-1}) = 1 - \frac{1}{2}t^{-1}.
\end{align}

Using the same technique (solve the problem by parts), you may try to recover Casella's answer to $F_Z(t)$.

Comment: Many many thanks! But this is really confused to me. It is strange to set $Y=y $ and do $X/y \leq t$. I will think better about this today.

Comment: In the first Integral you are Integrate the joint distribution of (x,y) right? Something like this: $P(X<yt, 0<Y<1)$ Right? And, of course, $P(X/y <t)$ is a Integral ?

Comment: Readers should be careful and not confuse X/Y with X|Y

Comment: @Laura In general, when two random variables are independent, then for any bivariate function $F$, we have $P(F(X, Y) \leq t) = \int F(X, y) f_Y(y) dy$ (make analogy of this formula to the (discrete) law of total probability). In this question, simply take $F(x, y) = x/y$.

Comment: Alternatively, as you suggested in your second comment, we can integrate with respect to the  joint distribution of $(X, Y)$, which is uniform over $(0, 1) \times (0, 1)$. This is slightly more convoluted (in my opinion) -- you need to sketch the region $\{(x, y): x/y \leq t\}$ then do the double integration over $(0, 1) \times (0, 1)$. This region, of course, also depends on $t$. Note this method is somewhat different from my answer. You can try it out by yourself --- if you encountered any difficulties, I can update my current answer.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Yes yes! I got it now! The independence hypothesis allows me to do that! Thanks